# How can I fix rectangle going to left down corner when dragged?

Tags: java, draggable, minecraft

I'm making a pvp client for a game called Minecraft (minecraft coder pack) and I'm having trouble with ClickGUI, a feature that allows you to enable other features in a window that appears in the middle of the screen. I have a problem that when I drag a rectangle, it always moves to its bottom left corner, like this:

https://streamable.com/qjbl71

I want the rectangle to stay in place when the mouse is pressed, only to move when the mouse is moved.

I have tried subtracting values like 50 from `categoryPositions.get(draggedCategory)` from the right and left from `// checking if any category is being moved, then replace category position`, but it only makes that rectangle is moving to the middle instead of left.

I found this method, that may help:

```
  public void draw(int mouseX, int mouseY){
    draggingFix(mouseX, mouseY);
    Gui.drawRect(this.getxPosition(), this.getyPosition(), this.getxPosition()+this.getWidth(), this.getyPosition()+this.getHeight(), this.getColor());
    boolean mouseOverX = (mouseX >= this.getxPosition() && mouseX <= this.getxPosition()+this.getWidth());
    boolean mouseOverY = (mouseY >= this.getyPosition() && mouseY <= this.getyPosition()+this.getHeight());
    if(mouseOverX && mouseOverY){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            if (!this.dragging) {
                this.lastX = x - mouseX;
                this.lastY = y - mouseY;
                this.dragging = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void draggingFix(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    if (this.dragging) {
        this.x = mouseX + this.lastX;
        this.y = mouseY + this.lastY;
        if(!Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) this.dragging = false;
    }
}
```

My `drawScreen` method that is executed every tick:

```
@Override
public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {

    // module category that is being moved
    Category draggedCategory = null;

    // checking if any category is being moved
    for (Map.Entry<Category, Boolean> categoryBooleanEntry : categoryMoved.entrySet()) {
        if (categoryBooleanEntry.getValue()) {
            draggedCategory = categoryBooleanEntry.getKey();
            break;
        }
    }

    // creating ScaledResolution to get scaled with and height
    ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc);

    // adding category positions one time
    if (!completed) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Category.values().length; i++) {
            int categoryXCoord = (sr.getScaledWidth() / Category.values().length) * i + (sr.getScaledWidth() / Category.values().length) / 2 - xOffset;
            // RectPosition values without offset
            categoryPositions.put(Category.values()[i], new RectPosition(categoryXCoord, 40, categoryXCoord, 40 + fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT));
        }
        completed = true;
    }

    // checking if any category is being moved, then replace category position
    if (draggedCategory != null) {
        categoryPositions.get(draggedCategory).left = mouseX;
        categoryPositions.get(draggedCategory).top = mouseY - offset;
        categoryPositions.get(draggedCategory).right = mouseX;
        categoryPositions.get(draggedCategory).bottom = mouseY + offset;
    }

    // drawing background
    Gui.drawRect(0, sr.getScaledHeight(), sr.getScaledWidth(), 0, 0x90000000);

    // copying values from enum category to arraylist
    categories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Category.values()));

    // getting max width for all categories
    for (Category c : categories) {
        if (fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(c.name()) > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(c.name() + offset);
        }
    }

    for (Module m : ModuleManager.modules) {
        if (fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(m.getName()) > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(m.getName()) + offset;
        }
    }

    int categoryCount = 0;
    for (Category c : categories) {
        int moduleCount = 0;
        int finalCategoryCount = categoryCount;

        int stringY = categoryPositions.get(c).top;
        int stringX = (categoryPositions.get(c).left - offset + categoryPositions.get(c).left - offset + maxWidth) / 2 - fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(c.name()) / 2;

        // drawing rectangle behind category name
        Gui.drawRect(categoryPositions.get(c).left - offset, categoryPositions.get(c).top - offset, categoryPositions.get(c).right + maxWidth, categoryPositions.get(c).bottom + offset, new Color(24, 97, 255).getRGB());

        // drawing category name
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString(c.name(), stringX, stringY, Color.cyan.getRGB());

        // getting modules belonging to current category
        modulesMatchingCategory = (ArrayList<Module>) ModuleManager.modules.stream().filter(m -> m.getCategory() == categories.get(finalCategoryCount)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (categoryExpanded.get(c)) {
            for (Module m : modulesMatchingCategory) {
                
                int x = categoryPositions.get(c).left;
                int y = ((mc.fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT + yOffset) * moduleCount) + (categoryPositions.get(c).bottom + yOffset);

                // boolean to check if the mouse is in rectangle
                boolean hovered = mouseX >= x - offset && mouseY >= y - offset && mouseX < x + maxWidth && mouseY < y + mc.fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT + offset;

                // drawing rectangle behind module name
                Gui.drawRect(x - offset, y - offset, x + maxWidth, y + fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT + offset, m.isToggled() ? new Color(12, 200, 242).getRGB() : hovered ? new Color(12, 74, 242).getRGB() : new Color(0, 119, 230).getRGB());
                
                // drawing string with module name
                mc.fontRendererObj.drawString(m.getName(), x, y, -1);
                moduleCount++;
            }
        }
        categoryCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating rectangles from Gui I created HashMap with Category and DraggableComponent method. Then I created for loop inside drawScreen method to call its DraggableComponent draw method.

```
// adding category positions one time
        if (!completed) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Category.values().length; i++) {
                int categoryXCoord = (sr.getScaledWidth() / Category.values().length) * i + (sr.getScaledWidth() / Category.values().length) / 2 - xOffset;
                draggableComponents.put(Category.values()[i], new DraggableComponent(categoryXCoord - offset, 40, maxWidth , fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT - offset, new Color(24, 97, 255).getRGB()));
            }
            completed = true;
        }
```